# Core Data: How to count entities in a one-to-many relationship with a specific attribute value?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

Here's an example of my data model:

- There are mailboxes
- Each mailbox has many messages
- Each message has a flag to indicate if it is unread

How can I count the number of unread messages **for a specific mailbox**?

I tried creating a fetch request in the data model editor, but I can't add a condition for the mailbox although the message entity has a relationship defined for its owning mailbox.

I know I'm not supposed to think in SQL when dealing with Core Data, but it feels so natural so say:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Messages WHERE unread = 1 AND mailboxId = 12345
```

Is there another way to get the unread message count other than looping through each message for a specific mailbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to count without fetching the objects, as that would take longer:

```
- (NSUInteger)countForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error
```

Returns the number of objects a given fetch request would have returned if it had been passed to executeFetchRequest:error:

You will also need to add a predicate to your fetch request (which is the WHERE clause).

e.g

```
NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Messages" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(unread == 1 && mailboxId == %i)", mailboxId]];
```

(I may have my predicate syntax wrong.... but you should get the idea)

Comment: Thanks for the super-quick response. Using the predicate as you suggested works. Is this the fact that I can't set a relationship condition in a fetch request then only a limitation of the data model editor?

Comment: You can set a relationship condition in the predicate using key paths, so mailbox.id will work (as @Ashley Mills suggested with his answer).

Answer (score 0):

The code below will count unread `Messages`, that have `unread == YES` and (assuming a `mailbox` relationship), where the mailbox's `id == 12345`

```
NSFetchRequest * request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Messages" inManagedObjectContext: context];

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(%K == %@) && (%K == %@)",
                                    @"unread", [NSNUmber numberWithBool: YES], 
                                    @"mailbox.id", @"12345"];

NSError * error = nil;
int count = [[self managedObjectContext] countForFetchRequest: request error: &error];
```

(NOTE: I like to use `%K` as a placeholder for the key path, as I declare constant strings for the attributes names.)

Answer (score -1):

The code below do the desired task:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MessageEntity" 
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(unread == %i)", 1];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *allResults = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

NSMutableArray *filteredSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(yourMailboxEntityObject *aMailBox in allResults) {
    if(aMailbox.mailboxId == your_desired_id)
        [filteredSet addObject:aMailBox];
}

//do your code
NSLog(@"unreaded messages: %d", [filteredSet count]);

//be sure to release the filteredSet...
[filteredSet release];
```

Comment: Wrong answer. @Mark wanted a count of Messages. Your answer requires returning objects, and THEN filtering the set further, and THEN counting them. Just let the DB do the work and use countForFetchRequest: